# mock a function with another function in the sam file with chai & chai-spies

Tags: node.js, chai

I have two functions in the same file, the first one calls the second one,

I want mock the second one and test the first one,

```
async function test(data) {
  try {
    const result = await access_to_data_base(data);
    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
}

async function test2(data) {
  try {
    const test = await test(data);
    // deal with the data that we retrieved 
    const result = treated_data();
    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
}

export.module = {
  test, 
  test2,
}
```

when I want to test the function test2 with mocked data, by example it will return a fake result that will return the final result or catch un exception, with chai and spy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you can't mock your function is because your design is coupled which is bad. Your function `test2` is dependent on `test` which makes it hard to test.

In order to decouple them you can do this:

```
async function test(data) {
  try {
    const result = await access_to_data_base(data);
    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
}

async function test2(results) {
  try {
    const treatedData = treated_data();
    return treatedData;
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
}

export.module = {
  test, //then have some higher level function tie them together.
  test2,
}
```

Now this allows u to test the functions individually and pass in mock data or mocked results. You should also separate the 2 functions into separate modules, to follow with the Single Responsibility Principle in order to achieve higher cohesion.